# llvm naming policy for llvm-IR variables and assembler symbols

Tags: assembly, llvm, llvm-ir, gnu-assembler

As I see llvm supports null-terminated strings including any character (0x01 to 0xff) as valid names for llvm-IR variables and assembler symbols. In my opinion such desicion may cause some problems.

1. It is difficult to edit programms in llvm-IR and assembler using text editors (Vim, Kate and others), when names contains "special" (nonprintable) charecters
2. LLvm and assemblers support escaping with double quotes, for example `"A B"` is a name with a space character. It would be logically to expect a printf like style in coding of special characters. I mean `"\n"`, `"\t"`, `"\xAB"`, but llvm-IR and assembler doesn't supports this style for names (but llvm suports \KL for initializers).

- in one hand `"A\n"` produces not `"A"` and `newline character` but name with all 3 bytes in object elf-file
- in other hand `"A\n"` and `"A\\n"` produces identical names for llvm

(So it seems that even llvm doesn't support special naming in a any kind of proper way.)

```
@"A\n"   = internal constant i32 1
@"A\\n"  = internal constant i32 2
```

```
$ clang-9 test.ll -S
test.ll:3:1: error: redefinition of global '@A\n'
@"A\\n"  = internal constant i32 2
```

3. What is about `@GOTOFF`, or `@plt`? How to differentiate names including `@GOTOFF` from assembler relocation specification? Why `"A B@GOTOFF"` can be assembling, but `"A B"@GOTOFF` doesn't works?
4. Bug https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18581 was opened in 2015 but even now gas doesn't support some characters in names, which llvm supports. For example
   `"A,B"` and `"A\B"` can't be assembling by gas.
   So llvm creates assembler dialect, which can't be assembling by gas.

Programming languages (C/C++, Rust, Go, Python, Java, ...) support only `letters`, `digits`, `'_'`, `'$'` characters in identifiers. Frontends using also `'.'`, `'$'`, `'#'` characters, but in any way they generate names valid in assembler (without any escaping by double quotes).

Probably, only llvm optimizations generate names with special characters. But these names are created only for globals with internal (static in C terms) linkage. So why not to use special pattern like `"__llvm_internal_global_Id_*"` for such globals (some names are reserved in all cases)?

So what are the reasons to use such naming policy? May be it is better to use a small but simple set of valid characters for naming?

Comment: Some bad assumptions here. Your description of [java identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) is totally wrong, so far I haven't seen any passes (what you call optimisations) that create non-ascii identifiers. And if gas doesn't work, why bother with it? All the cool kids compile to object code now.

Comment: Hm. My phrasing might be off. I can't tell, but I've spent six hours on one bug now and that tends to affect how I behave, so... Sorry about that.

Comment: I had debugging only one error about 3 weeks full time once (it was a faster version of mips interpreter in SpiderMonkey JIT from Firefox). It was "fun", so no problem. Which pass(es) creates "internal constant globals" now I don't know, but it seems like optimizations of string constants create a global with name is equal to value. So all characters from a string becames the characters of the name. This is the way (I think so). I see such sitation in clang, rust, python3/numba/llvmlite.

Comment: What you say about variable with name `".const.size mismatch for tuple, expected 1 element(s) but got %zd"`?

Comment: And now I want to understand is "special naming" a useful and great feature or a result of some random circumstances? If first then why for many and many years it still has the several problems in a realization? And what are the consequences of this in the future for assembler ecosystem? For example developers of gas try to support this feature. But after closing of Bug 18581 there was a lot commits (in svn log) to fix postbugs. And even now I think both llvm and gas hasn't full support of feature.

Comment: As I heard Ada has nested functions. After one commit in gcc accidentally nested functions became avaiable in C/C++. Developers of Linux kernels used this feature. Gcc's developers save feature. And now all gnu-compatible compilers must to support nested functions.

Comment: Based on the 2003-2004 commits I read, it's deliberate. And makes sense, because one of LLVM's goals is to simplify writing frontends. So its identifiers allow a big character set and have no length limit. There are other similar decisions too: No limit on the line length, no limit on the number of fields in a struct. Generated code often produce ugly results, I've seen ugly names, ugly types and ugly lines.

Comment: *May be it is better to use a small but simple set of valid characters for naming?* - That's what most front-ends do, I expect, especially when asm symbol names come from high-level language identifiers.  It seems normal to me that LLVM doesn't waste code on enforcing some restrictions on names; that would be slower and potentially inconvenient for some possible (future?) front-end.  Instead, the limits of what's actually usable come from LLVM-IR text parsers, and from common sense / human usability.  (At least that's my guess at how to look at the situation sensibly).

Answer (score 0):

I will try to summarize the interim results.

The llvm supports llvm-IR variable names and asm symbol names as a sequence of any characters. In general it looks as a good solution.

But current realizations has some special moments.

1. Llvm-parser can works with llvm-IR, in which both string initializers and names of the global variables contain escape sequences (using "\AB"-pattern where 0xAB is hex-code). But in assembler language the escape sequence doesn't used or/and doesn't worked (also there are readelf, objdump, gdb and so on). This fact creates problems for the use of text editors.
2. Assembler language uses special relocation modificators likes `@plt`, `@GOTOFF` and others after symbol names. So now it is a collision when a symbol name (in double quotes) includes a substring likes `"@plt"`. And I propose a simple rule for assembler lexic-parser

```
A@plt       - symbol with name 'A' and plt-relocation
"A@plt"     - symbol with name 'A@plt'
"A@plt"@plt - symbol with name 'A@plt' and plt-relocation
```

(so all in double quotes is a part of name, and all after double quotes or just in the end of a symbol name is a relocation modificator).

3. Gas declares the supporting (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Intro.html#Symbol-Intro), but in fact doesn't support `","` or `"\"` in symbol names. So the set of valid symbol names in gas is less then in llvm-as.

And I want to hope that these moments will be fixed in llvm and gas (if this is a correct description of the current situation).